# HttpClient Hangs on GetAsync for ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, httpclient, worker

I am attempting to get the status of a website in a .NET Core 3.1 worker service `await client.GetAsync` is only hanging on ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED from the host

Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseWindowsService()
               .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                        services.AddHttpClient();
                    });
```

Worker Constructor

```
   public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }
```

And later in the worker in the ExecuteAsync method.

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
var Siteresult = await client.GetAsync(_siteAdress);
```

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED from the server is the only way we can get this failing. The worker does not recover, We replicate this by
>   turning off the site in IIS (when we turn off the app pool we get a
>   helpful 503 and works well) we browse to the site in chrome and get
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED but the worker just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is wondering,   as per the documentation [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) using try-catch is required with an asynchronous call

```
        bool siteDown=false;

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_siteAdress);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        }  
        catch(HttpRequestException e)
        {
            siteDown = true; 
            _logger.LogError("Message :{0} ", e.Message);

        }
```